# Split string on consecutive new lines

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string that looks similar to this...

```
[1.2.1] - 08/30/2018
### Added
1. A new POPUP

[1.2.0] - 08/16/2018
### Added
1. Created a CHANGELOG
```

It will always be in a similar format, there will always be an empty line in between entries. What I am attempting to do is split the string on the empty line. I am attempting to use JS's `.split()` method, this is what I have;

```
MyString.split('/([\r\n]{2})/g');
```

These are the results I get:

```
[[1.2.1] - 08/30/2018↵### Added↵1. Changes POPUP↵↵[1.2.0] - 08/16/2018↵### Added↵1. Created a CHANGELOG]
```

The result I expect:

```
[[1.2.1] - 08/30/2018↵### Added↵1. Changes POPUP],
[[1.2.0] - 08/16/2018↵### Added↵1. Created a CHANGELOG]
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

-- EDIT

This is a very specific question about turning a single string into an array of text blocks, split on empty lines, not a general blanket question of "Why doesn't this regex work"

-- EDIT #2
After reviewing the comments, I have revised my method to use `MyString.split(/[\r\n]{5,}/)` and I had to add 2 additional empty lines between entries like so,

```
[1.2.1] - 08/30/2018
### Added
1. Changes POPUP



[1.2.0] - 08/16/2018
### Added
1. Created a CHANGELOG
```

Why must I use `{5}` as opposed to `{4}` to get the results I desire?

-- EDIT #3

After later revisiting the issue, I was able to get the desired results.
In this case the solution was to use `MyString.split(/[\r\n]{3,}/)` and reformat the entire block of data to have two blank lines between "versions" like so;

```
[1.2.1] - 08/30/2018
### Added
1. Popup to alert of new updates
2. Users now have a button to show closed quotes in addition to open quotes.

### Updates
1. Table now by default, hides closed quotes.
2. Refactored color key.
3. Refactored view control buttons.


[1.2.1] - 08/30/2018
### Added
1. Changes POPUP


[1.2.0] - 08/16/2018
### Added
1. Created a CHANGELOG
```

Ultimately a reformat of the data structure led to the desired results.

Comment: `MyString.split(/([\r\n]{2})/)`

Comment: There's another issue, actually. Even after removing quotes, you'll end up with an array of three elements and a `\n\n` in the middle -- this is because you capture the match. Remove the wrapping `()` as well.

Comment: Yea 2, in this case, splits the string into an array of 13 elements, using 3 gives an array of 3 elements and the index between each text block is the empty line.